# Angular 2 embedding

Tags: html, angular, iframe

I want to embed the following into a angular 2 web page. How can I achieve this?

```
<div id="cometchat_embed_synergy_container" style="max-width:100%;" ></div>
<script src="/cometchat/js.php?type=core&name=embedcode" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  var iframeObj = {};

  iframeObj.module="synergy";
  iframeObj.style="min-height:420px;min-width:300px;";
  iframeObj.src="/cometchat/cometchat_embedded.php"; 

  if(typeof(addEmbedIframe)=="function"){
      addEmbedIframe(iframeObj); 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Angular 2 use TypeScript to develop any component and implement any feature. I dont know what's Exactly your code mean,  but if you only want embed the code you can insert this code inside of index.html file between  tag.